# Search and replace in only certain tags and attributes in XML file by a regular expression

Tags: regex, xml, search, replace, geany

I have an XML file (call it module.xml) as below opened in
an editor like [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) or [Geany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geany):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>module/js/jquery.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>module/js/module-slider.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>module/module.css</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>module/js/module-video.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>module/js/nicEdit-latest.js</name></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="module/subscribe" name="module.left.subscribe" template="module/left-sidebar.phtml" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="module/subscribe" name="module.right.subscribe" template="module/right-sidebar.phtml" before="-" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="module" ifconfig="module/settings/quicklinks">
                <label>Module Title</label>
                <url>module</url>
                <title>Module Title</title>
                <prepare>true</prepare>
                <urlParams/>
                <position>99</position>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="footer_links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="module" ifconfig="module/settings/quicklinks">
                <label>Module Title</label>
                <url>module</url>
                <title>Module Title</title>
                <prepare>true</prepare>
                <urlParams/>
                <position>99</position>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
    <module_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="module/list" name="module_list" template="module/list.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </module_index_index>
    <module_create_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="module/list" name="module.create">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>module/create.phtml</template></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </module_create_index>
</layout>
```

Now I want to replace string `module/` with `mycompany/module/` in only tags and attributes containing `.phtml` filenames only, i.e. in content of the `template` attribute and `<template>` tag.

How can I do this with a regular expression? I am out of ideas when it comes to selective find/replace with regular expressions.

Comment: Why don't you use an xml parser?

Comment: This file is opnened in editor, I have ubuntu 14.04 installed, so unless you suggest me to use sed/awk, I cannot use xml parser in the editor(as I already stated in query) as I don't know if there is available for Geany/Notepad++

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/6MS8ry/1)?

Comment: Yes this works fine in the current xml, as long as the xml is unbroken and well-formatted, you're sure this would work, right ? Please then add this as answer with some explanation about regex used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this will work with properly formatted XML files.

---

You can use the regex `(?=.*\.phtml)module\/` and replace with `mycompany/module/`.

This:

```
(?=.*\.phtml)
```

Is a positive lookahead: it will ensure that the regular expression will be matched in the line. `module\/` is the string you want to replace with an escape on the `/`.

---

Also, you should read this [well-known answer about parsing with regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer and extra info, even on XML Parsing. Accepting it.